# Sign text message with private key and verify with public key

Tags: web3js, ethers.js

For my pet project I need to sign a text message with private key and then verify with a public key (or address also will be fine) on the other part of the system. I was able to sign a text message with ethers.js library, but I could not find out how to do verification. Can someone please help me? At least point me in the right direction...

Here is the code that I use to sign the message:

```
const wallet = ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic(mnemonicInput.value);
const signedMessage = await wallet.signMessage(challengeInput.value);
```

Comment: What code are you using to sign the message?

Comment: I edited the question to include the code